# Creating a view in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, list-view, sharepoint-enterprise, filter

I have a ticketlist which has ticket_id for 2 different locations,

> tickd1,tickd2,tickd3,tickd4 for Dallas
>   ticka1,ticka2,ticka3,ticka4 for Atlanta

Now I am trying to create 2 views, one for Dallas and 2nd for Atlanta.
The view in Dallas should have 2 conditions, one is the tick_ID contains "tickd" (which I was able to do oob) but the 2nd condition is to have only the latest created ticket. So this view will have only the latest created ticket for the location Dallas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply order the view as you have it by Created, descending order, and limit the number of items returned to 1 and you should have the desired affect.